# How to access storage from domain layer

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I think I may have some confusion about the domain/service layer separation.

In my application, the domain code needs to generate a system-wide unique identifier with a business meaning. This means it has to access the storage with exclusive access. I could do this directly in the domain code, but I think this is wrong for two reasons:

- Domain code should not access the storage (I think...)
- Getting an exclusive storage lock means I will block concurrent operations on other domain objects who also need this access, since the lock will be released only when the entire session is committed. It feels wasteful to use optimistic concurrency here: while the ID generation is quick, the business operations are relatively long, which means high probability of two concurrent business operations.

As an example, consider the following:

```
class UnitOfWork
{
    public OrderRepository TheOrderRepository { get; private set; }
    public void Commit() { /* ... */ }
}

class UnitOfWorkFactory
{
     UnitOfWork CreateNewUnitOfWork() 
     {
         var sess = CreateNewSession();
         var trans = CreateNewTransaction(session);
         return new UnitOfWork 
             { 
                 TheOrderRepository = new OrderRepository(sess, trans);
             }
     }
}

class OrderService // application service layer
{
    public void ProcessOrder(ID id, Details details)
    {
        using (uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateNewUnitOfWork())
        {
            Order order = TheOrderRepository.Load(id);
            order.Process(details);
            uow.TheOrderRepository.Update(order);
            uow.Commit();
        }
    }
}

class Order // domain layer
{
    public void Process(Details details)
    {
        // need to get a unique, business-related identifier here.
        // Where do I get it from?
    }
}
```

There are two options I could think of:

```
// Option 1 - get BusinessIdRepository from Service layer

class Order // domain layer
{
    public void Process(Details details)
    {
        // bad, because other Orders will block in Process() until my Process()
        // is done.
        // also, I access the storage in my domain layer, which is a no-no (?)
        var id = m_businessIdRepository.GetUniqueId(details);
    }
}
```

And:

```
// Option 2 - introduce a service. For this example, suppose the business ID is 
//            just an increasing counter

class BusinessIdBrokerService
{
    int GetBusinessId(Details details) 
    {
        int latestId;
        using (uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateNewUnitOfWork())
        {
            latestId = TheIdRepository.GetLatest();  // takes lock
            latestId ++;
            TheIdRepository.SetLatestId(latestId);
            uow.Commit();  // lock is released
        }

        return latestId;
    }
}

class Order // domain layer
{
    public void Process(Details details)
    {
        // domain layer accessing the service layer. Is this bad?
        var id = m_businessIdBroker.GetBusinessId(details);
    }
}
```

Now, option (1) has obvious disadvantages, but option (2) has the domain layer accessing the service layer. In all the diagrams I saw, this is a big no-no.

Following Jimmy Bogard's terminology (http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/) it looks like I want a Domain Service (as opposed to an Application Service) here, but this Domain Service will access the storage (not only through a repository: it will create an independent session + transaction.)

I should note that option (2) has the drawback that the ID generation cannot be rolled-back in case of a problem in Order.Process, because it's already been committed. I have no problem with that in my scenario. I'm fine with wasting IDs.

If it makes a difference, I'm using NHibernate as my ORM.

What approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the dependency from the Order to the IdBroker you could inject the IdBrokerService injected in the OrderService and pass the new Id to the Order.Process method as a parameter.

If you are fine with wasting id's that an independent service that generates a new id is probably the best solution in your case. You then add this service as a dependency to other services that get the ids and pass them to domain objects. This way your domain objects stay clear of any external interaction.

Comment: @Iulian Having the OrderService generate the ID is unfortunately not an option, since in my actual scenario the Order decides when it needs new IDs (it might need several, or none at all). What is your view on passing the IdBroker directly to the domain objects?

Comment: In this case you can pass the IdBroker to the domain object. This is commonly called [DoubleDispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). Just make sure that you pass it as an interface with the minimum required methods to reduce dependencies on other  components ( in your case probably just a GetBusinessId() method )

Comment: @Iulian Yes, this is what I intend to do. I ran into another funny problem: the service has to open a separate session + transaction, but my unit of work won't let it (because it's already in a transaction). This is really quite annoying. Any thoughts on solving this (other than using a threadpool thread...)?

Comment: You can create a new TransactionScope and pass a TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew as argument. It should create a new transaction for that scope.

Comment: @Iulian But I think that binds me to SQL Server, no? I found out that Rhino commons has something that looks good. I will look into using it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: TransactionScope is not related to SQL Server. Most(all?) the data providers for .net support TransactionScope. I would not be surprised if Rhino commons uses TransactionScope under the hood.